# How to disable auto brightening LCD

Tags: lcd, brightness

I am not talking about adjusting screen brightness through power management (this is a laptop), I'm not talking about how the screen brightness setting may be different between 'plugged in' and 'battery powered', and unplugging the laptop will suddenly change the brightness. I'm talking about:

I have a Dell XPS 15 (L502X), and with intell hd graphics driver installed (from a vanilla win7 64 bit install), I start to see a brightness change. (This is also before the nvidia driver install).

I set my desktop to black, and open notepad, fullscreen. Now the entire screen is a bright white. I then alt-tab back to desktop, all black.

This is the interesting part:

I alt-tab back to notepad (all white, fullscreen), and the brightness of the white slowly, every so slightly, incrementally steps up (less than even one brightness adjust as you would do via the power settings). Then you swith back to the black desktop, and barely you can tell it steps back down (the backlight on the black grows a bit darker). It is a small change, but noticeable in a dark room. Again back to white, and a step up to a brighter white.

It. drives. me. crazy. :)

It is very annoying googling for info (everyone has something about power management).
I can't find any setting in the intel hd graphics properties that affects this.
Oddly enough, I have an older install of windows on this same machine which doesn't do it, I fixed it once about a year ago and I can't remember how I did it (I work on quite a few pc's, I THOUGHT I tweeked something in the intel hd graphics properties, but nothing seems to stick this time).

1. What is this feature called?
2. How do I disable it?

**EDIT**

This does behave a lot like the automatic brightness adjustment that my smart phone exhibits. Ironically, that annoyed me as well (fixed with root and app)

I have tried to disable this feature, but here is a screenshot of my "Power" tab:

[image]

// The brightness feature is missing

I'm going to check what this tab looks like on my other disc (where I believe i once 'fixed' this)

**EDIT 2**

Turns out it was in the same view, but you have switch to change the power source to 'on battery' and disable "DIsplay Power Saving Technology"

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not seeing this effect myself (white/black Paint windows), and you've probably tried this already, but how about the `Automatic Display Brightness` setting in the Intel HD Graphics Properties (Advanced mode)?

[[image: Screenshot of setting]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep4B6.png)

Especially if it's in a dark room, it sounds like what a smartphone's 'light sensor' would do: when it's darker, turn down the brightness. When it's lighter, turn up the brightness. In a dark room, the increased brightness from a white screen might cause the sensor to see the whole room became brighter, a kind of feedback loop. And when the screen is black, the whole room becomes darker, causing the screen brightness to be lowered.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. See my edit/update.

Comment: Well suddenly it stopped, I'm in the process of running all updates and now I noticed it stopped doing it. Sheesh! I wish I had a handle on this thing. Couple notes: I tried the latest drivers from intel - they wouldn't install saying only oem's were allowed, also, I haven't checked how the prop tool looks on the other drive yet. Some other time. I still think you're right tho, giving you the answer.

Comment: see my answer's 2nd EDIT, the issue was found

Comment: That's interesting, I have that option on `Plugged in` as shown in my screenshot...perhaps a different driver version.

Comment: The problem is that the setting won’t stick and will revert.

Comment: Thank you, got me on the right track with Dell Latitude E7240. Was hidden under power options of the drivers as an on/off switch named 'Display Power Saving Technology'.

Comment: Does someone know how to have access to these settings when using linux?

Comment: @ppr Not that I know of. You might have more luck asking a new question specifically targeted at Linux. Also take a look at your desktop environment's settings, but I'm not really expecting anything there.

Answer (score 10):

Intel’s “power-saving feature” is indeed extremely aggravating. It is supposed to reduce power consumption, but all it does is to fade the screen in both brightness, and more importantly, *contrast*, but only when the display is primarily dark.

The problem with disabling the function in the Intel Media Control Panel as Bob has shown is that it just doesn’t stick. It gets reset to being on and in the middle when you reboot, and even under other circumstances (like changing the screen resolution, going into and out of standby, etc.)

I’ve searched high and low for a way to *permanently* disable this “feature”, and have eventually found a more-or-less satisfactory solution that works for most systems that use an Intel video-adapter (regardless of make or model).

1. Open the Windows *Control Panel*
2. Select *Power Options*
3. Click *Change plant settings*
4. Click *Change advanced power settings* to open the *Power Options* dialog
5. Expand the `Intel(R) Graphics Settings` branch (Figure 1)
6. Set it to *Maximum Performance*
7. Click `[OK]`, close, etc.

The screen brightness and contrast should no longer “adapt” to the overall brightness of what is being displayed.

You may as well change it for *all* of your power plans (Figure 2), even *Power Saver* because it does little to reduce battery power and only makes the display ugly.

It should be noted that this is not a perfect solution. It is analogous to moving the slider in the Intel MCP to `Maximum Quality`; there does not seem to be a way to outright disable it like un-checking the `Disaply Power Saving Technology` box (Figure 3). It may not be ideal, but at least it works and does not need to be repeated constantly.

**Figure 1**: Intel-specific power-plans settings

[image: Intel-specific options in Power Options dialog]

**Figure 2**: Make sure to edit each power-plan

[image: Power Plan drop-down in Power Options dialog]

**Figure 3**: Intel’s “power-saving features”

[image: Screenshot of power-saving page of Intel Media Control Panel]

Answer (score 6):

I did all this, this never worked. This is all that works:

1. Press "Windows Key + R" to open the command menu.
2. Type "services.msc" and press enter
3. Scroll through the list of services and look for "sensor monitoring service"
4. Permanently "Disable" the service in properties.

Voila.

Comment: Bam, that did it! Been trying to kill the darn Intel screen decimator for months. God only knows why they permanently enable (even if you explicitly turn them all off) their power saving features, but it's as annoying as hell.

Comment: Finally! You are my hero for today.

This is the only answer that works perfect. Full brightness!

Comment: In my case this has absolutely no effect. It was disabled from the beginning. Also I tried all previous answers and none work. Intel driver keeps changing brightness with its annoying "feature".

Comment: This did **not** work for me (Samsung Notebook 9).

Answer (score 2):

The new *Intel Graphics Control Panel* does not have the option, even under battery mode:

[image]

Therefore it is necessary to edit this in *power management*:

[image]

As far as my understanding goes, if you have the NVIDIA drivers also installed, you should only have the 3D graphics options under the NVIDIA control panel. Hope this helps.

Comment: And what if you don;t have this options on your laptop ?

Comment: I would think you don't have the latest drivers installed or are not using windows 8 or 10. Try downloading the latest drivers.

Comment: I install latest drivers, but as you know Windows 8,10 is not "desktop", Enterprise Os Like Windows 7

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but Windows 8 and Windows 10 definitely have desktop modes and are considered upgrades to Windows 7.

Comment: whatever, but of course there difference between drivers for desktop and Laptop and this options is missing in mine T440p Lenovo

Answer (score 0):

For Dell LCD, you need to turn off the "Smart Energy" and/or "Dynamic Contrast" features! These 2 will auto adjust your brightness. Look for it on the LCD screen menu - the hardware, NOT on the software!

Comment: Where is that menu?

Answer (score 0):

After tons of searching I found the correct option in advanced power options

Display>Enabled Adaptive Brightness

Using win 8.1

Comment: I also have win 8.1 and these settings are ignored by Intel driver.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling, changing profiles, settings, even going back to a 2006 driver, I finally found a solution. This works on my ASUS N551JM.

1. Search Windows for 'Intel'
2. Select 'Intel HD Graphics Control Panel'
3. Click the 'Power' square button
4. Click 'On Battery' tab
5. Disable 'Display Power Saving Technology' (I see it as the last option)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 machines the following registry setting works:

- Open `regedit` (Start → Run → `regedit`)
- Navigate to:
  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000`
- Find DWORD `FeatureTestControl`. It will have a hex value like `8200` (yours may differ)
- Logical-OR that value with `0x10`.
  For example, `8200` would become `8210`, `9240` would become `9250`, etc.
- Repeat for:
  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001`
- Reboot